# Complex has_many :through with block conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, has-many-through

I'm having a bit of difficulty figuring out how to do this in the "Rails" way, if it is even possible at all.

**Background:** I have a model Client, which has a `has_many` relationship called `:users_and_managers`, which is defined like so:

```
has_many :users_and_managers, -> do

  Spree::User.joins(:roles).where( {spree_roles: {name: ["manager", "client"]}})

end, class_name: "Spree::User"
```

The model `Users` have a `has_many` relationship called `credit_cards` which is merely a simple `has_many` - `belongs_to` relationship (it is defined in the framework).

So in short, `clients ---has many---> users ---has many---> credit_cards`

**The Goal:** I would like to get all the credit cards created by users (as defined in the above relationship) that belong to this client.

**The Problem:** I thought I could achieve this using a `has_many ... :through`, which I defined like this:

```
has_many :credit_cards, through: :users_and_managers
```

Unfortunately, this generated an error in relation to the join with the roles table:

> SQLite3::SQLException: **no such column: spree_roles.name**:
>
> SELECT "spree_credit_cards".*
>
> FROM "spree_credit_cards"
>
> INNER JOIN "spree_users" ON "spree_credit_cards"."user_id" = "spree_users"."id"
>
> WHERE "spree_users"."client_id" = 9 AND "spree_roles"."name" IN ('manager', 'client')

(Emphasis and formatting mine)

As you can see in the generated query, Rails seems to be ignoring the `join(:roles)` portion of the query I defined in the block of `:users_and_managers`, while still maintaining the where clause portion.

**Current Solution:** I can, of course, solve the problem by defining a plain 'ol method like so:

```
def credit_cards
  Spree::CreditCard.where(user_id: self.users_and_managers.joins(:credit_cards))
end
```

But I feel there must be a more concise way of doing this, and I am rather confused about the source of the error message.

**The Question**: Does anyone know why the AR / Rails seems to be "selective" about which AR methods it will include in the query, and how can I get a collection of credit cards for all users and managers of this client using a `has_many` relationship, assuming it is possible at all?

Comment: Does it need to be `roles:` instead of `spree_roles:` or do you have to `join` spree_roles as well?

Comment: @CWitty In the `join` method, you write the name of the relationship (which in this case is called `roles`), and in the `where` method, you reference the fully qualified table name, which in this case is `spree_roles`. The Spree framework namespaces everything; your relationships are usually the model name as you expect in regular Rails, but table names or class names all have the `spree_` or `Spree::` namespace prefix.

Comment: Gotcha I haven't worked in Spree

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `joins(:roles)` is being ignored because that can't be appended to the `ActiveRecord::Relation`. You need to use direct AR methods in the block. Also, let's clean things up a bit:

```
class Spree::Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :clients_and_managers, -> { where(name: %w{client manager}) }
  # a better scope name would be nice :)
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users,
            class_name: "Spree::User",
            foreign_key: :client_id

  has_many :clients_and_managers_roles,
            -> { merge(Spree::Role.clients_and_managers) },
            through: :users,
            source: :roles

  has_many :clients_and_managers_credit_cards,
            -> { joins(:clients_and_managers_roles) },
            through: :users,
            source: :credit_cards
end
```

With that setup, you should be able to do the following:

```
client = # find client according to your criteria

credit_card_ids = Client.
                  clients_and_managers_credit_cards.
                  where(clients: {id: client.id}).
                  pluck("DISTINCT spree_credit_cards.id")

credit_cards = Spree::CreditCard.where(id: credit_card_ids)
```

As you can see, that'll query the database twice. For querying it once, check out the following:

```
class Spree::CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user # with Spree::User conditions, if necessary
end

credit_cards = Spree::CreditCard.
                where(spree_users: {id: client.id}).
                joins(user: :roles).
                merge(Spree::Role.clients_and_managers)
```

Comment: Thanks Humza, I'm mulling over all the information in this answer, I'll see if this solves the issue.

Comment: @PaulRichter, remember to vote up the response / mark it as the answer, if it helped / solved your problem.

Comment: Yep not to worry, I haven't forgotten. I began parental leave and didnt get to properly explore your suggestion before leaving. I will do so hopefully soon. Have a +1 in the mean time.